# Error with python socket programming, winerror10057

Tags: python

This is my python code:

```
class SimpleWebServer():
    def __init__(self, port):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.port = port
    self.BUFFER_SIZE = 8192

    #Create a server socket
    self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)#YOUR CODE
    try:
        #Bind to a port
        #YOUR CODE; 1 line
        self.server.bind(('localhost', self.port))
    except socket.error:
        print('Bind failed %s' % (socket.error))
        sys.exit()

    #Listen to the server socket
    #YOUR CODE; 1 line
    self.server.listen(5)
def run_thread(self, conn, addr):
    # connection timeout after 60-second inactivity
    conn.settimeout(60.0)

    print('Client connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))

    while True:
        try:
            # Receives the request message from the client
            message = self.server.recv(1024)
            # .decode("utf-8") #YOUR CODE
            if not message: break

            # Extract the path of the requested object from the message
            # The path is the second part of HTTP header, identified by [1]
            filename = message.split()[1].decode()
            print('Client request ' + filename)

            # Extract the file extention to determine file type

            filename_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]

            # Open the local file f specified in filename for reading
            # Because the extracted path of the HTTP request includes
            # a character '\', we read the path from the second character
            f = open(filename)#YOUR CODE

            # Store the entire content of the requested file in a temporary buffer
            msg = f #YOUR CODE

            # Send the HTTP response headers to the connection socket
            # 1. HTTP version and status code
            # YOUR CODE 1-line
            #conn.send_response(200, addr)
            conn.sendall(bytearray("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"))
            # 2. Keep-Alive field
            # YOUR CODE 1-line
            #conn.send_head("Timeout = 5", "Max - 30", addr)
            conn.sendall(bytearray("Timeout = 5", "Max - 30"))
            # 3. Content length field

            # YOUR CODE 1 - 3 lines

            #conn.send_header("Content-length", len(msg), addr)
            conn.sendall(bytearray("Content-length", len(msg)))

            # 4. Content type field (based on the file type)
            # YOUR CODE
            #conn.send_header("Content-type", "text/html", addr)
            #conn.end_headers()
            conn.sendall(bytearray("Content-type", "text/html"))
            # Send the HTTP response body
            for i in range(0, len(msg), self.BUFFER_SIZE):
                end = min(i + self.BUFFER_SIZE, len(msg))
                conn.send(msg[i: end])

        # Exception handling
        except FileNotFoundError:
            # Send HTTP response message for file not found
            # YOUR CODE  1 - 3 lines
            self.send_response(404)
        except socket.timeout:
            #Socket timeout
            print("Conn socket timeout!")
            break
        except socket.error as e:
            #Other socket exceptions
            print("Socket error: %s" % e)
            break

    conn.close() # Close socket

def run(self):
    print('Waiting for connections on port %s' % (self.port))
    while True:
        #Accept a new connection
        try:
            #Waiting for connection request
            (conn, addr) = self.server.accept()

            #Start a new thread to handle HTTP request/response
            threading.Thread(target=self.run_thread, args=(conn, addr)).start()
        except:
            break

    # Close the server socket
    self.exit()

def exit(self):
    """Close server socket"""
    self.server.close()
```

I call the class here:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage="%prog ServerPort")
    options, args = parser.parse_args()
    if len(args) < 1:
        parser.error("No ServerPort")
    else:
        if validate_port(args[0]):
            server_port = int(args[0])
        else:
            parser.error("ServerPort invalid!")

    #Create and start the server
    server = SimpleWebServer(server_port)
    server.run()
```

I call the script via powershell and I get this error:

```
Client connected with 127.0.0.1:2654
Socket error: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

I'm running this command in my browser to try and access this socket:
http://localhost:8888/index.html

I have no clue what I should be doing to fix this. There is a lot of documentation for python socket programming and I've tried many of the different methods but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: I think for the line `message = self.server.recv(1024)` should be conn instead of server.

Comment: So I just tried that, but that needs to be an integer in order to determine how many bytes to read.

Comment: I mean you should have `message = conn.recv(1024)`

Comment: OH! Ya that works thanks!